# How to establish Connection with Existing SAP GUI: SAP Logon 730 window

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I am new towards learning and Scripting SAP GUI, I am in desperate help towards automating the SAP GUI window in C# with the Targeted Framework .NET Core 3.1, I had tried installing the "SAP.GUI.Scripting.net" via NuGet Package Manager. But, Unfortunately the Package version is deprecated. Parallelly I did tried finding similar packages for "SAPGUIScript.Activities" & "SAPAutomation" to download. But the Problem I find after installing is "Package may not be fully compatible with the project which I am working on".

Could someone please help me on resolving my problem of suggesting me to use the Compatible Package for the Project which I am working on with the Targeted Framework as mentioned above? It could be a great help if someone can please suggest me at the earliest...

[image: Error Screenshot]